# How can a Moore machine be converted into an equivalent Mealy machine and vice versa?

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

Moore machine is a finite-state machine whose output values are determined by its current state only.

Mealy machine is a finite-state machine whose output values are determined both by its current state and the current inputs

I just don't see what can be changed for one to be proved equivalent to other.

Comment: A Moore machine is basically just a degenerate Mealy machine; only a very small technical change in the form of the output function is required to turn it into a true Mealy machine. The other conversion is harder; [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpne8_W-AdA) does a pretty good job of illustrating the procedure with a simple example that captures all of the important ideas. Watch it and see if you can generalize the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this'll help, as I'm not very familiar with comp sci, but consider a general discrete example
$$x_{k+1} = f(x_k), \quad k=0,1,...,n-1 \qquad (1.1)$$

where $f(x_k)$ determines the next state.

Then consider a different discrete case where we have a input variable $a_k$ so that the above becomes

$$x_{k+1} = f(x_k,a_k), \quad k = 0,1,...,n-1 \qquad (1.2)$$

From a quick Wikipedia read, you may change Eq (1.1) so that we have $f_k$ instead of $f$... so we have multiple functions and we *may* make them produce equivalent results to the Eq. (1.2)
$$x_{k+1} = f_k(x_k), \quad k = 0,1,...,n-1 \quad (1.3)$$

Here is a [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine#Relationship_with_Mealy_machines) I read.